# Merge lines into single line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
< Dec 2, 2015 2:51:49 PM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <cphypprod1v..com> 
<AnalyticProviderServices0> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 
'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel> <> <1449085909249> <BEA-

101017> <[ServletContext@462961596[app:bea_wls_deployment_internal 
module:bea_wls_deployment_internal.war path:/bea_wls_deployment_internal spec-

version:null]] Root  ServletException.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 

>

< Dec 2, 2015 2:51:49 PM EST> <Warning> <RMI> <cphypprod1v.sherwin.com>   <AnalyticProviderServices0> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue:   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1449085909264> < BEA-080003> < RuntimeException thrown by  
rmi server: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke 
(Ljavax.management.ObjectName;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.rmi.Marshal 

>
```

I need to modify it so it looks like:

```
  < Dec 2, 2015 2:51:49 PM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <cphypprod1v..com> <AnalyticProviderServices0> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel> <><1449085909249> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@462961596[app:bea_wls_deployment_internal module:bea_wls_deployment_internal.war path:/bea_wls_deployment_internal spec-version:null]] Root  ServletException. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded  >

< Dec 2, 2015 2:51:49 PM EST> <Warning> <RMI> <cphypprod1v.sherwin.com>   <AnalyticProviderServices0> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue:   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <> < 1449085909264> < BEA-080003> < RuntimeException thrown by  rmi server: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke (Ljavax.management.ObjectName;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.rmi.Marshal >
```

Everything between `<` and `>` must be on the same line. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your example files as code. I have edited your question to what I *think* you meant, but please make sure I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: Is the `<br>` actually part of your file?

Comment: no..i changed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">\n+";ORS=">\n";FS="\n"} {$1=$1}1' yourfile
< Jan 20, 2016 11:58:09 AM EST  Test1 Sample Test1 >
< Jan 20, 2016 11:58:09 AM EST Sample Test It is not  T1 T2 >
```

If you want a blank line between each output, you can add an extra `\n` to the `ORS` i.e.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">\n+";ORS=">\n\n";FS="\n"} {$1=$1}1' yourfile
```

(although this may also add a trailing blank line at the end of the file).

Comment: If i want space  between each line.. how to do in that case

Comment: @Naresh please see updated answer - note that @StephaneChazelas nice `sed` answer does not suffer from the extra trailing newline

Comment: but i am getting all the lines in one line.

Comment: i have file in the same format , when i use this command i am getting everything in one line...

Comment: I have change the format as per my file .. please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

**For (GNU sed)**:

```
sed -e ':x' -e 'N' -e '$!bx' -e 's/\n/ /g' -e 's/ </\n</g' yourFile
```

**For (BSD sed)**:

```
sed -e ':x' -e 'N' -e '$!bx' -e 's/\n/ /g' -e 's/ \</\'$'\n</g' yourFile
```

This is how I've done it:

- Create a label via `:x`
- Append the lines to the pattern space with `N`
- Branch to the created label - the `x` at the first of the command - `$!bx` so it won't apply the space-associated substitution on the last line since we should keep the last newline
- Then the substitution replaces every newline with a space() on the pattern space
- And then another substitution replaces every `<` followed by a space with a newline followed by a `<`.

Comment: In GNU sed, the `<` in the final expression needs to be UNescaped I think i.e. `'s/ </\'$'\n</g'` or just `'s/ </\n</g'` (else it's treated as a word boundary rather than a literal `<`)

Comment: @steeldriver yes you're utterly right, thanks mate. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in effect, you want to remove all the newline characters except those that follow a `>`, so:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!>)\n//'
```

would do. `(?<!...)` is a negative look behind operator. So, it's `\n` provided it's not preceded with a `>`.

If it's to remove all newline characters that are between matching `<...>` pairs *and*, as per your new sample, those may nest, then that becomes more complicated:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{<(?:(?0)|[^<>])*>}{$& =~ s/\n//gr}gse'
```

Here using recursion in perl regexps (`(?0)` refers to the whole regexp again).

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, `paste` and `sed`

```
awk '/</{a=1}/>/{print;a=0}a' file | paste -d "" -s | sed 's/></>\n</g'
```